# npm publish with automation token in .npmrc returns 404 "not in this registry" error

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I'm testing a publishing workflow locally so that I can then implement for CI. Note: I don't get this error if I'm logged in manually, via the username, password, email OTP prompts, but am trying to set things up so that publishing can be done autonomously in CI.

My .npmrc looks like this:

```
_auth=npm_fooBAR
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$TOKEN
```

The token in my `.npmrc` is an [Automation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-viewing-access-tokens#creating-access-tokens) token so I don't get 2FA'd. I'm publishing a new version to my already existing package.

On `npm publish ./.dist` I receive

```
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@my-package%2fmy-package - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@my-org/my-package@1.1.0-alpha.1' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Am I missing something in my `.npmrc`? Also, if I'm publishing, why would the error be telling me about install options?

Comment: Im having the same issue, tried regenerating a new token even - and even went as far as to visit the package on npmjs.com, to go to the packages *Settings* tab, and to change *"Do not require maintainers to use  2FA"* to ***"Require maintainers to use 2FA or Automation Tokens"***. Was there anything else you did besides generate a new token? Following the same docs as you, to the "T".

Comment: NVM that, my original token was fine, in my case I am using GitLab-CI, I'm leveraging group variables (set to ***Protected*** and *Masked*), and triggering a publish from a tag. In my case, I either needed to choose to unprotect the variable or to make my tags protected; I did the later and it published perfectly using the access token. Before then, it was an empty token getting replaced which was incorrectly stating that the package didn't exist, rather than that I was not authenticated.